# curl instagram api return 500 error

Tags: api, curl, instagram

I have Load Balancing in 4 servers, but only one server url return 500 error.

Servers are using the same OS and the same curl version.

> centos-release:CentOS release 6.8 (Final)

```
curl 7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) 
libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.21 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
Protocols: tftp ftp telnet dict ldap ldaps http file https ftps scp sftp
Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz
```

This url is not working(like, comment,...)

```
curl -F 'access_token={access_token}'
```

https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media-id}/likes
Errer message is 'Oops, an error occurred.'

This url is working.
curl 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media-id}?access_token={access_token}'

Help me, How to fix them

Comment: Having the exact same problem. Did you solve it?

Comment: I don't solved that,
So i did exclude problem server.

Comment: I was trying to create a subscription, every thing I try gives me either  HTTP 400 or a HTTP 500. However, /media/{media-id}/likes is working just fine. I gave up on the subscription.

Comment: I have the same issue here with subscriptions....trying now for days to get it to run but it seems the instagram api is completely broken at the moment...